# Push Notification for iOS7 and iOS8 in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to register push notifications for iOS7 and iOS8 in Swift. Back in Objective-C I could have done something like:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
        UIUserNotificationType UserNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationTypeNone;
#endif
```

This is not possible in Swift.

**How do I register Push Notification for iOS7 and iOS8 together?**

Answer (score 2):

```
static func setupPushNotifications() {
        // Register for Push Notitications
        let userNotificationTypes:UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Sound, .Badge]

        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().respondsToSelector("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications") { //this should be done with getobjc method
            // iOS 8 Notifications
            let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            // iOS < 8 Notifications
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])
        }
        print("Push notifications setup complete")
    }
```

Appdelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    //iOS7 method
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    //iOS8 method
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ``this should be done with getobjc method``?

Comment: I read that this way is better. if objc_getClass("isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications") != nil {
never tried it for this case tho. and left a note so i can try it sometime. the current one does work at the moment

Comment: I think you can also do: ``UIApplication.sharedApplication().respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings")``

Comment: yeah, few ways, not sure which is the best

Comment: How do I receive the callback from the notification? How do I know if the user accepted or not?